# Auth0 Graph.cool Invalid The provided idToken is invalid

Tags: react-native, auth0, graphcool

I am developing a react native mobile app using auth0 and graph.cool.  I've configured the client credentials properly within graphcool.  When I try to create a new user by calling the createUser mutation with the id_token received back from auth0 I keep getting GraphQL Error: The provided idToken is invalid. Please see https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id_token for how to obtain a valid idToken.

I have also changed the JsonWebToken Signature Algorithm from RS256 to HS256 but that is not working either. I am using the id_token generated from the authentication API after logging in a user by using the /oauth/token endpoint. I would greatly appreciate any help on this topic.  Thanks in advance.